# I have a question in hodge decomposition and ker(δ)/im(δ)-an example

Tags: homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

I was reading the textbook "Hodge Decomposition
A Method for Solving
Boundary Value Problems" by Günter Schwarz.

I wanted to find a simple example of the “hodge-morrey-friedrich decomposition”. I thought that a punctured 2-dimensional disk would be a good example, since it is related to de rham cohomology.

So My conclusion was that I could think 1-form $(xdx+ydy)/($x^2$+$y^2$)$ is ismomorphic to
$H^1$$(M,δ)$

Is this example appropriate?

Since my major is not mathematics, there might be some mistakes in my questions. If you find any errors or issues, I would be very happy to hear from you. And of course, I would also be very happy to hear the answer to my question.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150049/discussion-on-question-by-junyeol-choi-i-have-a-question-in-hodge-decomposition); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.