# Is 1-form $(xdx+ydy)/(x^2+y^2)$ co-closed but not co-exact?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

It is easy to check that the 1-form
$$\frac{xdx+ydy}{x^2+y^2}$$
is co-closed, just by using $★δk=d★k$. But since $$\frac{xdx+ydy}{x^2+y^2}=-1×★ \frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2},$$
I thought that there are no 2-form $a$ that satisfies $$\frac{xdx+ydy}{x^2+y^2}=\delta a.$$
(As same reason that $\frac{-ydx+xdy}{x^2+y^2}$ is closed form but not exact form.) So am I right? Is the 1- form
$$\frac{xdx+ydy}{x^2+y^2}$$
co-closed but not co-exact?

And additionally, is this related with homology or cohomology?

Comment: What form $\star\,dx$ is depends on the dimension of the space you are in. May I ask what that is?

Comment: @KurtG. Of course, 2-dimension plane, sir. Where *dx=dy and *1=dxdy

Comment: Ok. Let me give it  a go: If there were a $2$-form $a$ that satisfies 
$$
\frac{x\,dx+y\,dy}{x^2+y^2}=\delta\,a=\star\, d\star\,a
$$
and $\star\,a$ is a $0$-form. Let's call it $f\,.$
Then
$$
\star\frac{x\,dx+y\,dy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x\,dy-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}=d\star\,a=df\,.
$$
This brings us back to the known case of the closed but not exact one-form.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you for proving my statement, sir. And as it is  co closed but not co exact, can we think it as an element of cohomology group ker(δ)/im(δ)?

Comment: Naively I would say yes but I confess that I am not an algebraic geometer/topologist. You may want to add some tags and few more buzz words to the post to draw some expert's attention.

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you. If you posted your answer as the "answer"(not comment), I would actually selected your answer. Thank you so much, and have a nice day.

Comment: Still the same mistake I corrected five times in the comments to the post you’ve deleted. You still seem not to have read the definition of a quotient vector space. No, a differential form is not an element of the quotient. As I said numerous times, it represents an element of the quotient; elements of the quotient are a equivalence classes. Please go learn the basics.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your comment, professor. I will go back to basic. P.s. I have not deleted my post... you can still find it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810759/i-have-a-question-in-hodge-decomposition-and-ker%ce%b4-im%ce%b4-an-example